# Current density and total Current

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electric-current

I was given a problem that stated two different current densities and was asked to find the total current. This was all given in cylindrical coordinates. I'm not going to use the function the problem gave me, i'll just make one up similar. 
Let

$$
\boldsymbol J=\begin{cases}20\sin(x)\ \hat z  & \rho < a\\0 & \rho\ge a \end{cases}
$$

I know how to integrate to get the current within a region. But if I wanted the total current would it just be the current enclosed when $\rho > a$? Since this takes into account both current densities?

Comment: Yes, the total current would just be the current enclosed when $\rho>a$

Answer (score 1):

That's correct. There is only a non-zero contribution from the current density which is enclosed by the radius of the cylinder. Specifically, you have no current due to outer regions just because of the way you have defined your current density in this particular example. Thanks,